# Small Self Joining query slow

Tags: sql-server, performance, join

Hi have a table which holds 42,400 rows. This is pretty small for SQL Standards.

The table holds location for a facility, and is designed as a parent/child relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentLocationId] [int] NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [LocationTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_Location] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

It has a Foreign key to a LocationType table, which has 5 rows.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Location]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_location_locationtype] FOREIGN KEY([LocationTypeId])
REFERENCES [ref].[LocationType] ([Id])
GO
```

It also has a self join to it's self.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Location]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_LocationLocation] FOREIGN KEY([ParentLocationId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([Id])
GO
```

A parent can have many children. However, we have a fixed number of location levels. And the Location information is queried a lot.

So, I have implemented a view to get the location data.

It's a bit long, so it's at the bottom, however, the idea is to populate a row for ear level, and then join to it's children, doing a union and returning the result set.

For example:

Select where Location Level = 1 (Root)
Then
Select where Location Level is 2, and join to it's parents.
Then
Select where Location Level is 3 and join to it's parents, and it's parents.

This seems to be a performance issue now. Is there a better way to achieve the results I am looking for, which is, a row per location...

The first row is the root node...
2nd is the root, with it's first child
3rd is the root with it's 2nd child..

An example of doing a select on a specific location:

[image]

```
SELECT
    l1.Id as LocationId,
    l1.LocationTypeId, 
    lt.DisplayName,
    l1.ParentLocationId,
    l1.Description AS thisLocationName,
    l1.IsDeleted,
    l1.Description AS Level1, 
    NULL AS Level2, 
    NULL AS Level3,
    NULL AS Level4,
    NULL AS Level5,
    NULL AS Level6,
    NULL AS Level7,
    NULL AS Level8,
    NULL AS Level9,
    NULL AS Level10
FROM [dbo].Location l1
INNER JOIN ref.LocationType lt
   ON lt.Id = l1.LocationTypeId
AND lt.level = 1

UNION 

SELECT 
    l2.Id AS LocationId,
    l2.LocationTypeId,
    lt.DisplayName,
    l2.ParentLocationId,
    l2.Description AS thisLocationName,
    l1.IsDeleted | l2.IsDeleted, 
    l1.Description AS Level1, 
    l2.Description AS Level2, 
    NULL AS Level3,
    NULL AS Level4,
    NULL AS Level5,
    NULL AS Level6,
    NULL AS Level7,
    NULL AS Level8,
    NULL AS Level9,
    NULL AS Level10
FROM [dbo].Location l1
INNER JOIN [dbo].Location l2
    ON l2.ParentLocationId = l1.Id
INNER JOIN ref.LocationType lt
   ON lt.Id = l2.LocationTypeId
AND lt.level = 2

UNION

SELECT 
    l3.Id AS LocationId,
    l3.LocationTypeId,
    lt.DisplayName,
    l3.ParentLocationId,
    l3.Description AS thisLocationName,
    l1.IsDeleted | l2.IsDeleted | l2.IsDeleted,
    l1.Description AS Level1, 
    l2.Description AS Level2, 
    l3.Description AS Level3,
    NULL AS Level4,
    NULL AS Level5,
    NULL AS Level6,
    NULL AS Level7,
    NULL AS Level8,
    NULL AS Level9,
    NULL AS Level10
FROM [dbo].Location l1
INNER JOIN [dbo].Location l2
    ON l2.ParentLocationId = l1.Id
INNER JOIN [dbo].Location l3
    ON l3.ParentLocationId = l2.Id
INNER JOIN ref.LocationType lt
   ON lt.Id = l3.LocationTypeId
AND lt.level = 3

UNION
.... (This occurs for 10 levels)
```

Here's so demo data for the table.

```
INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(1, NULL, 'A Building', 1)


INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(2, 1, '1st Floor', 2)

INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(3, 1, '2nd Floor', 2)

INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(4, 1, '3rd Floor', 2)

INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(5, 1, '4th Floor', 2)



INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(6, 1, 'Boardroom', 3)


INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(7, 1, 'Main Office', 3)

INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(8, 1, 'Directors Office', 3)

INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(9, 1, 'Kitchen', 3)



INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(10, 2, 'Office', 3)

INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(11, 2, 'Meeting Room', 3)

INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(12, 2, 'Kitchen', 3)

INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(13, 2, 'Gents WC', 3)

INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(14, 2, 'Ladies WC', 3)



INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(15, 3, 'Office 1', 3)

INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(16, 3, 'Office 2', 3)
INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(17, 3, 'Office 3', 3)
INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(18, 3, 'Office 4', 3)
INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(19, 3, 'Meeting Room', 3)
INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(20, 3, 'Staff Room', 3)



INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(21, 4, 'Small Office', 3)

INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(22, 4, 'Medium', 3)

INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(23, 4, 'Large Office', 3)
INSERT INTO Location 
(Id, ParentLocationId, Description, LocationTypeId)
VALUES
(24, 4, 'Meeting Room', 3)
```

I have attempted the CTE version recommended below:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwLocations3]
WITH SchemaBinding

AS
with h as (
    select l.Id, l.ParentLocationId, l.Description, l.LocationTypeId, l.IsDeleted
             , convert(varchar(100), null) level2
             , convert(varchar(100), null) level3
             , convert(varchar(100), null) level4
             , convert(varchar(100), null) level5
             , convert(varchar(100), null) level6
             , convert(varchar(100), null) level7
             , convert(varchar(100), null) level8
             , convert(varchar(100), null) level9
    from dbo.Location l
    where ParentLocationId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    select l.Id, l.ParentLocationId, l.Description, l.LocationTypeId, l.IsDeleted
            , case when l.LocationTypeId = 2 then l.Description when l.LocationTypeId > 2 then h.Description end  level2
            , case when l.LocationTypeId = 3 then l.Description when l.LocationTypeId > 3 then h.Description end  level3
            , case when l.LocationTypeId = 4 then l.Description when l.LocationTypeId > 4 then h.Description end  level4
            , case when l.LocationTypeId = 5 then l.Description when l.LocationTypeId > 5 then h.Description end  level5
            , case when l.LocationTypeId = 6 then l.Description when l.LocationTypeId > 6 then h.Description end  level6
            , case when l.LocationTypeId = 7 then l.Description when l.LocationTypeId > 7 then h.Description end  level7
            , case when l.LocationTypeId = 8 then l.Description when l.LocationTypeId > 8 then h.Description end  level8
            , case when l.LocationTypeId = 9 then l.Description when l.LocationTypeId > 9 then h.Description end  level9
    from h
    inner join dbo.Location l on l.ParentLocationId = h.id
    )
SELECT
        h.Id AS LocationId,
        h.LocationTypeId,
        lt.DisplayName,
        h.ParentLocationId,
        h.Description AS thisLocationName,
        --h.Level1, 
        h.Level2, 
        h.Level3,
        h.Level4,
        h.Level5,
        h.Level6,
        h.Level7,
        h.Level8,
        h.Level9
        --cte.Level10
     FROM h
    INNER JOIN ref.LocationType lt
    ON lt.Id = h.LocationTypeId
```

But this is returning a selection in 1,500ms.

Comment: UNION removes duplicates, it is slower than UNION ALL

Comment: Thanks @Used_By_Already - I amended my View, but this made no difference.

Comment: add sample data to your question (not all 10 levels needed, just a few rows) don't use images for this. also add the expected result from that sample of data.

Comment: please also post the execution plan

Comment: A union statement like this is probably less efficient than a recursive CTE (both in terms of readability and performance) and your performance would likely be improved with indexes on the columns youre joining on (assuming you don't have these indexes)...

Comment: OK to both. @Squirrel - Is there a way to post the execution plan? When I view it, it's rather large....

Comment: @ZLK - a CTE would be great here! I'm just not sure how I'd apply it.

Comment: I think the only way to maybe improve this query, is to make it into an index view. However, because of the Union - I can't, I believe. Is there a way to make it into an Index View?

Answer (score 0):

Try a recursive CTE (common table expression) e.g.

```
with h as (
    select l.Id, l.ParentLocationId, l.Description, l.LocationTypeId, l.IsDeleted
             , convert(varchar(100), null) l2desc
             , convert(varchar(100), null) l3desc
    from Location l
    where ParentLocationId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    select l.Id, l.ParentLocationId, l.Description, l.LocationTypeId, l.IsDeleted
            , case when l.LocationTypeId = 2 then l.Description when l.LocationTypeId > 2 then h.Description end  l2desc
            , case when l.LocationTypeId = 3 then l.Description when l.LocationTypeId > 3 then h.Description end  l3desc
    from h
    inner join Location l on l.ParentLocationId = h.id
    )
select
*
from h
order by LocationTypeId, ParentLocationId
;
```

[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/BJWZW76583)

```
|    | Id | ParentLocationId |   Description    | LocationTypeId | IsDeleted |   l2desc   |      l3desc      |
|----|----|------------------|------------------|----------------|-----------|------------|------------------|
|  1 |  1 | NULL             | A Building       |              1 | False     | NULL       | NULL             |
|  2 |  2 | 1                | 1st Floor        |              2 | False     | 1st Floor  | NULL             |
|  3 |  3 | 1                | 2nd Floor        |              2 | False     | 2nd Floor  | NULL             |
|  4 |  4 | 1                | 3rd Floor        |              2 | False     | 3rd Floor  | NULL             |
|  5 |  5 | 1                | 4th Floor        |              2 | False     | 4th Floor  | NULL             |
|  6 |  6 | 1                | Boardroom        |              3 | False     | A Building | Boardroom        |
|  7 |  7 | 1                | Main Office      |              3 | False     | A Building | Main Office      |
|  8 |  8 | 1                | Directors Office |              3 | False     | A Building | Directors Office |
|  9 |  9 | 1                | Kitchen          |              3 | False     | A Building | Kitchen          |
| 10 | 10 | 2                | Office           |              3 | False     | 1st Floor  | Office           |
| 11 | 11 | 2                | Meeting Room     |              3 | False     | 1st Floor  | Meeting Room     |
| 12 | 12 | 2                | Kitchen          |              3 | False     | 1st Floor  | Kitchen          |
| 13 | 13 | 2                | Gents WC         |              3 | False     | 1st Floor  | Gents WC         |
| 14 | 14 | 2                | Ladies WC        |              3 | False     | 1st Floor  | Ladies WC        |
| 15 | 15 | 3                | Office 1         |              3 | False     | 2nd Floor  | Office 1         |
| 16 | 16 | 3                | Office 2         |              3 | False     | 2nd Floor  | Office 2         |
| 17 | 17 | 3                | Office 3         |              3 | False     | 2nd Floor  | Office 3         |
| 18 | 18 | 3                | Office 4         |              3 | False     | 2nd Floor  | Office 4         |
| 19 | 19 | 3                | Meeting Room     |              3 | False     | 2nd Floor  | Meeting Room     |
| 20 | 20 | 3                | Staff Room       |              3 | False     | 2nd Floor  | Staff Room       |
| 21 | 21 | 4                | Small Office     |              3 | False     | 3rd Floor  | Small Office     |
| 22 | 22 | 4                | Medium           |              3 | False     | 3rd Floor  | Medium           |
| 23 | 23 | 4                | Large Office     |              3 | False     | 3rd Floor  | Large Office     |
| 24 | 24 | 4                | Meeting Room     |              3 | False     | 3rd Floor  | Meeting Room     |
```

Comment: Thanks. I have run it, but Description, l2desc and l3desc are all the same... Description should be the description of the current location, then l1 should be the root of the tree that this location belongs to, and then l2 is the child of that root... recursively to the selected location. I'm trying to work out how the CTE is working - it seems like it's a good step, but the results seem wrong right now.

Comment: sorry, I have amended the example, but it might not completely solve for all description columns

Comment: I tried this but got really bad results with the 44,000 records. My original query is returning in 1,100ms, I made a new one removing the join to a lookup table, and get that back in 300ms... and the cte version is 1,500ms...

Comment: I managed to improve the original query by removing the join to a lookup (To get the Location Type name). I then changed the query into a CTE (With all the unions etc) and then joined the CTE once to the lookup table. That went from 1000ms down to around 300... which is helpful, but ... I'm hoping to grab it down to under 100ms...

Comment: you should be using UNION ALL (no doubts on this one)